# WinAPI functions to hook in order to capture network

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, windbg

I would like to write hooks to print sent/received data (i.e. network data, packets sent and received) for a certain process.
What is the lowest level I could place that hook on (maybe one or two specific function/s that are being eventually called internally by the functions detailed below)?

```
WS2_32!WSARecv
WS2_32!WSARecvFrom
WS2_32!recv
WS2_32!recvfrom
WS2_32!send
WS2_32!sendto
WS2_32!WSASend
WS2_32!WSASendDisconnect
WS2_32!WSASendMsg
WS2_32!WSASendTo
```

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want this? What is the problem such hooking is supposed to solve? Have you though about hooking into an even lower level, or using a library such as [WinPCap](https://www.winpcap.org)?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Of course there are many tools that do that.
I want to do it for a personal project I'm working on. I tried to do it using IDA but I didn't seem to find one root function to hook so I thought I better ask here

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you do not want to reinvent the wheel so get a hooking library like MinHook https://github.com/TsudaKageyu/minhook/ or Microsoft Detours https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/project/detours/
small example with minhook

```
int YourDetourFuncHere(
SOCKET     s,
const char *buf,
int        len,
int        flags
){
  // your code here.
  return RealFunction(s, buf, len, flags);
}
void hookex(){
MH_Initialize();
MH_CreateHook("ws2_32.dll", "send", YourDetourFuncHere, &RealFunction);
MH_EnableHook(MH_ALL_HOOKS);
}
```

That is just sort of pseudo code since you should not be copying and pasting in the first place ;) and you should add more error checking according to the libs documentation.

If you want to see all traffic globally use a NDIS driver and just send the data to usermode. You can have a thread in usermode that will keep calling ReadFile() and setup a IRP_MJ_READ on the driver side and just fetch the packet data from the driver.
Also for other browsers it can vary. For instance, Firefox might be PR_Write and other such programs or browsers might use different protocols etc so depending on your goal you should look where you wish to place your hook.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your comment. My question addressed the function that I should hook to capture as many API calls as possible, rather than how to perform hooks

Comment: I would then hook  NtDeviceIoControlFile() when it tries to send data to AFD.sys driver. This would work for majority of the cases.